# Arduino based clock with 4 pieces 4" 7 Segment LED Displays

Tags: arduino, clock, 7segmentdisplay

I was going through multiple tutorials on how to create an Arduino clock with 7 segment displays. I planned to build one and purchased 4 large (4 inches) 7 segment 1 digit displays. The displays run on 12v. And moreover, I got Common Anone displays.

Could you please guide how I can power up 12v Common Anode 7 segment displays by multiplexing? I can write the code part of it and the clock logic. I need help to design the circuit part to drive the 12v Common Anode LEDs with Arduino.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I precisely needed a circuit. A circuit which would be able to power up 4 pieces of 4 inch 7 segment LED display, and with the help of multiplexing I will employ my arduino to lit it up to display desired numbers. So definitely the circuit should consists of an Arduino Unit (Nano, Uno or anything bigger) and 4 numbers of 7 segment digit display. Hope this shortens the scope of the answer.

Comment: Did the tutorials not cover this?

Comment: Can you add a link to the datasheet of the 7-segment LED display that you have.

Comment: No, most of them are using Common Cathodes. Any none of them practically gave an idea of how to drive a higher power LED.

Comment: I don't have the Manufacturer's datasheet available with me, I purchased it offline and got a printed copy of this:
https://e-radionica.com/productdata/LD3361BS.pdf
See Point #1.10 Common Anode 4.0 Inch (100.0mm)

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: Your question needs work, please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for how to write good questions. Maybe there is a communication gap but there is no good reason multiplex the power of an LCD. Please learn how to write good questions.

Comment: My question was on 7 segment LED, not LCD. I wanted to do multiplexing and at the same time had a challenge to draw large amount of current due to the large size of the LED. I finally got a solution with Sparkfun's big digit driver.

Comment: Edited my question and shortened it. Any answer now?

Comment: Since you have answered your own question and accepted your answer, it should mean the problem is solved. If the problem is solved, why do you reformulate the question in order to reopen it? Either it means the answer you posted is actually not an answer, or it means the question has evolved and it should have been a new question. In both cases, something is wrong. Moreover, it is hard to guess where exactly you're stuck in your design. It would be simpler to answer if you actually put some effort in trying to come up with some schematic and submit it to us.

Comment: @dim I am not sure why the question is marked 'too broad'. Thus I narrowed the question. I didn't get any response with a circuit diagram which I needed. I am still looking for a working design if possible. The solution which I got is an assembled module readily sold on Sparkfun.

Comment: Too broad here means that we don't understand where you're stuck. Hence to answer, we would have to do the full design for you. Which is too broad. You don't have to have a working design to post here (if you had it, it wouldn't be necessary to post), but having an approximative design answers many questions we could have reagrding what you're trying to do, and how you plan to do it. With the information we have currently, it is hard for us to guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I got this from Sparkfun https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13279 and it does exactly what I need. Well, I needed 4 of these drivers to drive 4 big digits.

Comment: So then, it was just a shopping question?

Comment: I didn't get a 'non-shopping' answer that helped me to solve the need :) ... I have figured out the circuit on the driver. Do you need it? I will be glad to share...

Comment: Well, I don't need it myself. But if you develop your answer in this way, it will give more value to it, so don't hesitate to do so.

Comment: Sure, I will share the diagram in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Just use a voltage level converter after the multiplexer. As long as the display does not draw more current than the converter can handle, in which case you will nee to wire transistors instead. Here is an example with 12 channels:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/2x-Level-Shifter-Logic-Level-Converter-12-Channel-5V-to-12V-or-12V-to-5V-/251606065490